# A civilian for two weeks?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-cell

At the end of The Cell (2000), Peter Novak is no longer an agent. At least not for two weeks. He is still allowed to investigate and such, however, as he's at Carl's house.

What happened?

Catherine asks him how long he'll be a civilian for, and he responds "two weeks."

Has he been suspended for two weeks? He did nothing wrong. He broke no chain of command to my knowledge.

Comment: It's possible to make no mistake and still lose. He likely embarrassed himself or the department, leading to the suspension.